# Splitting character row into columns using Regex

Tags: r, regex, split

I have a single-column dataset where each row is a concatenated string of varying length. I am trying to split each row into 3 columns using regular expressions. An example of the dataset is something like below.

Column 1 (ID) would be the initial string of letter-numbers. This is always the same length (in this case, 24 characters)

Column 2 (Type) would be the middle bit. This can vary in terms of length and character type (ampersands, spaces, slashes, commas, but never numbers)

Column 3 (Numerical) would be the string-final numerical sequence which is also fixed in length (in this case, 14).

```
c23uij49753dfd3273shdjsh /Animals/Birds/Cardinal 0.873289139232
91873nc9248jfe08jsdif894 /Animals/Mammals/Felines/Tigers 0.989734823872
38939137fhjnffnf73nxlppa /Transportation/Automobiles & Vehicles/Ford-Explorer 0.983947399348
```

```
data <- data.frame(
  string=c("c23uij49753dfd3273shdjsh /Animals/Birds/Cardinal 0.873289139232", 
          "91873nc9248jfe08jsdif894 /Animals/Mammals/Felines/Tigers 0.989734823872", 
           "38939137fhjnffnf73nxlppa /Transportation/Automobiles & Vehicles/Ford-Explorer  0.983947399348"))
```

I've been trying to use extract(), but can't get the regular expression that targets the middle section right. Something like below is on the right track, but doesn't get me there.

```
output <- extract(data, string, into=c('ID', "Type", "Numerical"), "(.{24)([a-zA-Z]*)(.{14})
```

Comment: try with `output <- str_match(data$string, "^(.{24})([^0-9]+)(.{14}) (.+)$")`

Comment: I think you had a small typo. Removing the (.{14}) worked great! Thank you!
`output <- str_match(data$string, "^(.{24})([^0-9]+)(.+)$")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^(\w{24})\s+(.*?)\s+(\d+\.\d+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qc6Qab/1). In R code, define as `"^(\\w{24})\\s+(.*?)\\s+(\\d+\\.\\d+)$"`.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\w{24})` - Group 1: twenty four alphanumeric or underscore chars
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\d+\.\d+)` - Group 3: one or more digits, `.`, one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.